# sudo apt autoremove showing unmet dependencies I can't remove for mongodb

Tags: software-installation, mongodb

When I run autoremove I get the following. I am in root and have tried running sudo apt install -f without luck. This issue occurred because I ran sudo apt install mongodb and realized that the command installs v 3.6 and I needed the latest version, so I used mongodb documentation to install mongodb 4.4. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
mandi@mandi:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
mandi@mandi:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: This question has been marked as already answered, but the answer linked is a different question

Comment: @M1ke seems fitting to me? Why do you think it is different?

Comment: The linked issue is someone running `apt install` not as root, i.e not using sudo. Thus their error mentions "are you root" and the solution is to use sudo. In this question the issue raised _is_ being run as root, and the error is different, so it seems the problem must be different.